# visibility of gridview in asp.net and C#

Tags: asp.net

I'm using a gridview to show the uploaded file and be able to download them, when I run it the browser it doesn't show until I upload something , how to solve this problem???

Comment: could you please provide code which you have done?

Comment: Most probably GridView will not get displayed until you assign some datafields to it.